# TableModel Change the value of a jcheckbox cell after a second click in other checkbox

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jtable, boolean

I have a table with a checkbox column, I am able to show the table like i want and I make editable just the column where the checkbox is placed. The problem is when I select the checkbox the render paint in the right way the checkbox but the value in the tablemodel isn't changed, this value just change until i give click in another checkbox, always the last checkbox that I choose doesn't reflects his value in the TableModel. The classes that I am using are:

**Checkcell**

```
class CheckCell extends DefaultCellEditor implements TableCellRenderer{

    private JComponent component = new JCheckBox();    
    private boolean value = false;

    public CheckCell() {
        super(new JCheckBox());
    }


    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return ((JCheckBox)component).isSelected();        
    }


    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {

        ( (JCheckBox) component).setBackground( new Color(200,200,0) );

        boolean b = ((Boolean) value).booleanValue();
        ( (JCheckBox) component).setSelected( b );
        ( (JCheckBox) component).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER); 
        return ( (JCheckBox) component);     
    }


    @Override
    public boolean stopCellEditing() {        
        value = ((Boolean)getCellEditorValue()).booleanValue() ;
        ((JCheckBox)component).setSelected( value );
        return super.stopCellEditing();
    }


    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (value == null)
            return null;         
         return ( (JCheckBox) component );
    }

}
```

**CheckRender**

```
class CheckRender extends JCheckBox implements TableCellRenderer {

    private JComponent component = new JCheckBox();


    public CheckRender() {
        setOpaque(true);
    }


    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

       ((JCheckBox) component).setBackground( new Color(0,200,0));

       boolean b = ((Boolean) value).booleanValue();
       ((JCheckBox) component).setSelected(b);
       ((JCheckBox) component).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER); 
       return ((JCheckBox) component);  
    }

}
```

**My Model**

```
class DynaTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    public DynaTableModel() {
        super();
    }

    public DynaTableModel(final DynaTableBean dynaBean) {
        super(dynaBean.getContent(), dynaBean.getHeaders());
    }    

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        if (col == 0)    
        {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) {
        super.setValueAt(value, row, column);
    }
```

Could you help me with this? what is missing me to change the value in the jtable when this change in the checkbox.

I am new in java and I think that there are something that is missing me.
Thanks in advanced.

---

Being a little more explicity, when I ticked the checkbox and I tried to recover the value from the TableModel the value is wrong by example if I ticked the first checkbox and I tried to recover the value using:

valor = (Boolean) tablemodel.getValueAt(i, 0);

I am getting false when this should be true, but if I check the first checkbox and later the second one the value of the first checkbox now is fine(true) but the second is still false is a kind of bug but I don't find the way to avoid this.

Someone knows how to avoid this.

Comment: don't re-invent the wheel, more often than not the outcome is a triangle ;-) Or in other words: your editor implementation is invalid. And checkbox editors for boolean values are supported by default ... simply learn to use them correctly

Answer (score 2):

> I have a table with a checkbox column, I am able to show the table
>   like i want and I make editable just the column where the checkbox is
>   placed. The problem is when I select the checkbox the render paint in
>   the right way the checkbox but the value in the tablemodel isn't
>   changed, this value just change until i give click in another
>   checkbox, always the last checkbox that I choose doesn't reflects his
>   value in the TableModel

- [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) has built in support for `JCheckB`ox as `TableCellRenderer` and `Editor`
- `Boolean` value represens `JCheckBox` in `XxxTableModel`, you would need to put there `true` or `false` (1st column)
- override [`public Class getColumnClass(int c) {`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data),

Comment: I already pass a vector with the value false to the first column and that is working fine, the problem comes when I choose any checkbox, the tablemodel recognize(update) this change until I choose another checkbox, so the first one is changed in the tablemodel but the last one that I choose still has the same value.

Comment: @user2824421: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18985782/230513).